# Conflicting cookie results on Chrome

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools

Below, Chrome shows a cookie on current page by viewing `Inspect->Resources->Cookies`, but why is there nothing by reading "document.cookie".

[image]

**@EDIT**

The cookie is firstly returned from the server via `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=01E9...; Path=/myUrl/`.

It's intended to remove the cookie on the client but fails. Probably the trailing "/" of the `cookie path` has caused this nasty issue.

**@EDIT 2**

The "problematic" cookie is set to `HttpOnly` by the server, so client scripting can neither change, remove nor read it. This resource [protecting your cookies](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) explains the reasons. BTW, `Chrome devtools` can do nothing more than either view or clear it.

Comment: Any info on how to reproduce this would be helpful... (i.e. might be a specific Chrome version, a specific setting on that cookie, or a combination of the two, etc.)

Comment: Is it a HttpOnly cookie?

Comment: Yes, it is HttpOnly cookie.

Comment: Now it's mostly clear that the client is prohibited the write access to `HttpOnly cookie`.

Comment: The client is actually evicted from any access to `HttpOnly cookie`, so reading on `document.cookie` appears empty.